# Split a string into two strings using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to read a file that contains data like this

```
['19df', 'b35d']
['fafa', 'bbaf']
['dce9', 'cf47']
```

..

I need to split in into

```
i = 
19df
fafa
dce9
```

and

```
q=
b35d
bbaf
cf47
```

I tried doing this,

```
for x in line:
    i, q = x[:len(x)/2], x[len(x)/2:]
```

unable to split, please help!